# Equality of date in SQL

Tags: sql, jsp, date

I have stored records in a table with a column storing SYSDATE.

Now I ran a query and displayed all rows of this table in a JSP page. I gave a button for selecting a row and updating it.

I want to select that particular row in SQL table to update it. For this, the date column of every row is unique and I want to use it for choosing that row using a query like

```
Update Table 
Set record_seen='Y' 
Where sub_date Like to_date('01-01-2014','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The above query works but how can I use the entire `sysdate like '2014-07-11 10:37:52.0'` in the above query?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to update if you had a surrogate key for the row. It avoids date precision quirks and date collisions.

Comment: Change the format to `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS'`.

Comment: errrgh, this looks terrible, you definitely need a surrogate key (usually an auto incrementing integer)

Comment: I thought of doing that. This table is used for storing bill records. Thousands of rows are added everyday, will using a surrogate key be a good option?

Comment: I found using a surrogate key/ storing date as string:to_char(SYSDATE) helpful. Guess surrogate key would also work faster in comparison and take much less storage space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment. I suspect that you have solved your problem.  The query would look something like:

```
Update Table 
    Set record_seen='Y' 
    Where to_char(sub_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2014-07-11 10:37:52';
```

The downside is that this will not use an index, unless you implement a functional index, something like:

```
create index idx_table_tochar_subdate on table(to_char(sub_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Presumably, you are using Oracle.  Adding a pseudo-column to each row can be a pain, because it requires creating a sequence and a trigger for each table (at least in older versions of Oracle).  You can also use the `rowid` pseudo column for this purpose.  You wouldn't show the `rowid` to the user, but you would store it and use it for the update.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) is more information on `rowid`.

Comment: rowid is exactly what I am looking for! This way I don't have to make a separate sequence and can keep the table schema intact.